# Django celery executes method every other Friday?

Tags: cron, django-celery

I'd like to have a method fire every other Friday using Django Celery. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to crack the [crontab](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#crontab-schedules) code.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Celery beat also lets you specify intervals instead of crontabs, you can set an interval of 14 days and start it running on a Friday.

It's not as precise as a crontab and you have to be careful if you restart the celery beat process i'm not sure if it restarts the timers or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can find simple description here: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#crontab-schedules